# Are complementary slackness conditions always *sufficient* to obtain the dual solution from an optimal primal solution?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Suppose that I have a guess for the optimal solution $x^\star$ of a linear program $P$. Let $D$ be the dual of $P$. One way to verify optimality of $x^\star$ is through complementary slackness conditions. That is, for any $x^\star_i > 0$, we know the corresponding constraint in $D$ must be binding, and for any non-binding constraint in $P$, the corresponding variable in $D$ must be 0.

My question is, are these conditions always sufficient to construct an optimal solution $y^\star$ for the dual, given that $x^\star$ is optimal for the primal? What if the majority of variables in $x^\star$ are zero and the majority of constraints in the primal with respect to $x^\star$ turn out to be binding? Then we won't be able to infer much about the variables of the dual through complementary slackness.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

Comment: @MarkL.Stone From your comment, I get that the answer to my question should be trivial and that I should be able to find it in Wikipedia. But I can't. Do you mind to at least give me a yes/no answer? Are C.S. conditions sufficient?

Comment: KKT conditions are necessary and sufficient for a Linear programming problem. There is more than complementary scakcness.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. But does this mean complementary slackness is not always sufficient?

Comment: It's possible some other conditions are violated.

Comment: The dual optimal solution might not be unique.  For that matter, the primal optimal solution might not be unique.

Comment: Thanks @BrianBorchers that was actually very insightful.